# Error related to Excel importing using read_excel

Tags: r, data-import, readxl

I'm  new to R and studying how read_excel() and excel_sheets() work, trying to use two such codes below. These are intended to read the second sheet of an excel file.

```
output <- read_excel(excel_sheets("population.xlsx")[2], 
            path = "population.xlsx")

output <- read_excel(excel_sheets("population.xlsx"), 
         sheet = 2, path = "population.xlsx")
```

The first code runs successfully, but the second one doesn't with the error

```
Error: length(x) == 1L is not TRUE
```

I'd like to know the reason why 
 it happens and how I can fix it.

The document of read_excel says it can use 'sheet' argument to select which sheet to read, which I guess is identical to stating the number of the order of a character vector ( i.e. `excel_sheets("population.xlsx")[2]` in this case).

Answer (score 2):

Just `read_excel(path = "population.xlsx", sheet = 2)` should work. Your first code is getting a list of all sheets and then selecting the name of the second; `read_excel` accepts both integer position and sheet names as the argument for `sheet`.

You may be confused because you need to know something about [argument matching](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/functions.html#argument-matching); named arguments are matched and then they are matched left to right. So in the first example, `path` is specified, and then the `excel_sheets` call is passed to the `sheet` argument. In the second, you specify `sheet` and so I think it will get passed to the `range` argument, which is supposed to only accept a character vector of length 1. That's the source of the error you have.